# I want to create routes from database Data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-routing

I want to retrieve data from the database and create the dynamic route.

For example, in Laravel web route file we write :

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug){
  return $slug; 
});
```

So, I want to create this code after retrieving data from the database. and based on the data I can create the dynamic route with params or passing model data to the view.

And also how do I create dynamic view files. Like for different layout or from the database data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please add some examples of how you expect to use the dynamic routes.

Comment: Ok let's say to create different routes I need to write:

Route::get('/home', function(){ return 'Home' }); 

in web.php while developing the app. 

But I want to create it dynamically with the help of UI from the front End. 

Like I'll write the code Route::get('/post', function(){ return 'Post' }); 
in a form and then press save and the next time when I want to access the route I'll be able to do so.

I want to do something like this but with the help of database. 

Let me know if it's clear.